# MySql Connector/Net current source (as of Feb-17-2012)

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

So not sure if this is the best spot BUT:

MySql's Connector/Net source code at their [repository at launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/connectornet) has no updates beyond 6.2 and Aug-2011, whereas the site is claiming 6.5.2 RC2, so I'm curious as to where the actual code repository is... anyone aware of where it's been moved to, so I can branch the 6.5.2 RC2 and fix a bug and possibly submit the fixes?

Comment: btw: already posted a question on Launchpad project asking this question as well, but no responses because I think its not being used anymore (so therefore, not being checked very often)

Comment: Ever figure this out? The launchpad page gives a 404. Seems like it would be difficult to take closed source since its GPL, but then again, this is Oracle we're talking about...

Comment: I would like to know this too, I want to see if they have started work on a MigrationSqlGenerator for Entity Framework Automatic Migrations before attempting to write my own

Comment: Actually, it seems they have created a MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator, its in the MySql.Data.Entity package but it only seems to work with EF 4.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launchpad is not up to date for now.

For getting Connector/NET source code go to
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

For example for 6.6.4, download the file mysql-connector-net-6.6.4-src.zip

Comment: Any updates on this? Where is the source?

Comment: The source is in the URL mentioned, for MySql for Visual Studio it's on http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

Comment: Let me rephrase: Where is the repository? Its not on SVN, its got a stub on Launchpad... I'm attempting to make some revisions to the code but there is no repository to be found for me to submit those to. I'm sure there IS a repository (somewhere), just curious as to where exactly.

Comment: There was a launchpad, but lagged way too much, so it was removed (don't know why I work as developer only). Probably in the future a public repo may appear again. In the meantime, the only way to do contributions is submit bugs in bug.mysql.com & attach the code/diff.

Comment: Thank you. Lastly - is there a format for the diff that is accepted or can any diff format be provided? I.e. SVN diff / patch file?

Comment: We currently use Git, so the git diff, or a any text diff will do. Also instead of a single diff with several fixes, several diffs with a single fix each is better (faster peer review, etc.)